# What do I need to know in order to help with bug/papercut fixing?

Tags: programming

I think the question is clear enough. One thing though, I'm interested in the programming part not something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll find this ['How To Fix a bug'](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/HowToFix) wiki page quite useful. It mentions about how to generate a patch or a branch merge with the fix.

Programming skills required depend on the application or the bug you are working on. 
If the bug is just a simple wording change you don't require much programming knowledge, just patience for *Finding* the line. ;)

I'd suggest you first have a look at the [list of bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bugs?field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED), when you find something interesting, it will give you a better idea of what is required to fix that bug.

While working on a bug, make sure you mark the bug as *In-Progress*, as mentioned in the  [papercuts wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PaperCut#Fixing%20a%20paper%20cut).

If you have any questions while working on a bug, feel free to ask on the [Papercuts Ninja mailing list.](https://launchpad.net/~papercuts-ninja)